# can any one tell me what is wrong in my java code

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;


public class shift {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String args[])
    {


        String speech = "Sentence:NounPhrase VerbPhrase:NounPhrase :Art Noun:VerbPhrase : Verb | Adverb Verb: Art : the | a : Verb :jumps | sings |: Noun:dog | cat | ";

        HashMap<String, String> hashmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String a;
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(speech,":");

        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
          String key=st.nextToken().trim();
          String value=st.nextToken().trim();



          StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(value,"|");

          while (st1.hasMoreTokens()) {

              a=st1.nextToken().trim();

              hashmap.put(key, a);


          }


        }


        Set set = hashmap.entrySet(); 
        Iterator ia = set.iterator();





    while(ia.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)ia.next(); 

            System.out.println(me.getKey()+"->"+me.getValue());


     }
}

}

the output is
Noun->cat
NounPhrase->Art Noun
Art->a
Sentence->NounPhrase VerbPhrase
Verb->sings
VerbPhrase->Adverb Verb
```

this code is missing some values to return such as the `the jumps etc are not show`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure I get your question fully, but keep in mind that a HashMap can only store *one value per key*.

If you want to store multiple verbs for the key `"Verb"`, then you would have to declare the map using something like:

```
HashMap<String, Set<String>> hashmap = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();
```

and store the words mapped to by `"Verb"` in a set.

Here is a brushed up (working) version of the code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Shift {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String speech = "Sentence:NounPhrase VerbPhrase:NounPhrase :Art " +
                        "Noun:VerbPhrase : Verb | Adverb Verb: Art : the | " +
                        "a : Verb :jumps | sings |: Noun:dog | cat | ";

        Map<String, Set<String>> hashmap = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();

        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(speech, ":");

        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String key = st.nextToken().trim();
            String value = st.nextToken().trim();

            StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(value, "|");

            while (st1.hasMoreTokens()) {
                String a = st1.nextToken().trim();

                if (!hashmap.containsKey(key))
                    hashmap.put(key, new HashSet<String>());

                hashmap.get(key).add(a);
            }
        }

        for (String key : hashmap.keySet())
            System.out.printf("%s -> %s%n", key, hashmap.get(key));
    }
}
```

Comment: is there is any way to get the values as one by one like [NounPhrase ,VerbPhrase]  as NounPhrase and then VerbPhrase

Comment: There are implementation of multi maps already existing, e.g. in Apache Commons Collections, or Guave. If you use such you can leave the algorithm as it is.

Answer (score 2):

You're overwriting the existing value when you call hashmap.put(key, a), since you're assigning a value to a key that already has a value.